# Custom filter in Excel

Tags: excel, date, filter, criteria, digits

I need to filter my excel sheet to show only record that’s match following criteria:-

Only show 8 digit numbers cells
only show date format with 12-3-2022 cells
Any idea

Thanks
Al

Comment: Filter column by specific date. Post a screenshot of your sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try formulas with if statements using:

length =len() for 8 characters long
search = search() for a specific date?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ID Code           Date                             Time                                                                                        89657874 2025-03-01                   7:00:00
89657894 2021-03-05                    14:00:00
9657874          2021-05-01                    7:00:00
896478          2021-05-08                    14:00:00
8965787412  2021-12-08                     20:00:00
BR